# Meaning of dangling pointers

Tags: c, pointers

How can I determine dangling pointers in C? Here is example of this.

```
int *fun(void) {
    int i = 2;
    return &i;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean determine? Decide if the return value of your `fun` is a dangling pointer or not? Or to pass/return the value (or address) of the `i` variable?

Comment: `i` is a local variable. It doesn't exist after `fun` returns, but you're returning a pointer to it.  Same if you return a pointer to malloced memory but freed the pointer before  returning it. Such pointers dangle. It isn't rocket science.

Comment: I meant return value of function is dangling pointer or not?

Answer (score 0):

Here in below code block

```
int *fun(void) {
    int i = 2;
    return &i;
}
```

you are returning a *address of a local variable* that means you are returning a **dangling pointer** & it causes **undefined behaviour**, your compiler could have warned you like

> error: function returns address of local variable
>   [-Werror=return-local-addr]
>
> ```
>      return &i;
> ```

above if you could have compile with flags like `gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror test.c`